# Scrape website data without BS or selenium (Python)

Tags: python

Basically my scenario is that I have the webpage open and want to copy some of the text from the website that is open on my screen ( there is a whole login process every time ) . For Security reasons, I do not want to have to continuously login to the webpage and for that reason, requests are not suitable. I also do not want to use selenium as it will open up a new browser when I wish to use my existing one. My question is with my browser already open on the page I want info from, is there some sort of script I can make that will retrieve certain information on the page for me and save it somewhere (almost like a macro but it's able to retrieve certain elements) . Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly.

One way might be to download the entire .html and process the respective data "locally" after downloading the .html.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "request", like with postman, you don't need to log in each time. If you have a valid JWT token you will skip login. But that depend how your stuff work (lack of details in your question).

I don't know about selenium, but with puppeteer (a concurrent), you can re-use an already installed browser instead of downloading a new one.

Also... do you even need selenium or puppeteer ? Can't you just run some code into your console (browser console) ? You can create and save snippets in source tab in chrome. If you need access to your file system directly (meaning the data you collect being downloaded automatically in download folder, or having download pop-up to choose folder, is not enough for you), you may give a look at TamperMonkey extension. Or maybe you need to make a chrome extension.

---

Update after reading your comment @JeanVanNiekerk:

```js
// to get user name of the one asking.
console.log(
  document.querySelector('#question .user-details a').innerText
); // 'Jean Van Niekerk'
```

```js
navigator.clipboard.writeText('stuff').then(
  e => {
    console.log('Copied text ready !');
  }
);

// If you write that above in the console, you
// will get `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Document is not focused.`
// This is a security (maybe it can be disabled for your special case, another
// option is to make an extension that has this kind of rights).

// To try it out right now, paste this code bellow into you console, and swiffly click on the page (anywhere)
setTimeout(() => {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText('stuff').then(
  e => {
    console.log('Copied text ready !');
  }
);
}, 1000);
// Ctrl+V to paste your text :)
```

Comment: This is interesting, I haven't thought of this before, so basically there is a way to copy certain elements of a webpage ? For example on stackoverflow, if I accessed this webpage and wanted to grab, my username and message , I could do that and copy it to my clipboard automatically?

Comment: @JeanVanNiekerk I updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Your answer was SO SO helpful, this is exactly what I was looking for, the only thing is being able to automate this process . So going on the webpage and copying multiple elements and populating the info into a .txt , but I really appreciate your answer, its been the most helpful thing so far lol!

Comment: @JeanVanNiekerk If it is helpful, you can upvote or mark it as answer. As for automation for multiples pages, I still think tools like puppeteer, or just making requests and parse body, would be a good choice. Whatever you choose, if you log in once manually to your website, you could retrieve the JWT token and use it for his validity period (1day, 5min, depend on back-end config) to make toons of requests until token is invalid. That mean your script would never know what identifiers you used. But this won't work if your backend use for example basic-auth for authentification.

Comment: My last question basically is how to remove the debugger codes on the right side of every line it prints (I don't want this when I copy all text as when I copy the text it includes the debugger codes in console) thanks !

Comment: @JeanVanNiekerk , you can remove the `console.log` if you don't want the `VM3771:1` part. It will be evaluated by the console on the line bellow. You could also use regex to clean up the text in a second time.